# Will push notifications through GCM be supported in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using eclipse IDE for development. I followed lots of tutorials and implemented push notifications in my project but I'm not getting the GCM Registration id, So my questions is: will **eclipse** support the push notifications or not?

Below is the code snippet; if you need more clarity please comment below.

```
        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    Log.v("testing", "testing");
    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    Log.v("regId", regId);
    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
        Log.v("registerd","am here");

        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);

    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            Log.v("hello","am here");

            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
```

Comment: Did you register the services in the manifest? P.S.: why make your life harder? Migrate to android studio, it is way better

Comment: I was registered in manifest <service android:name="com.info.socialnetworking.app.meetatbars.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService" />

Comment: Did you turn on the Google cloud messaging from the Google developer console and get the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer by using following tutorial.. [link](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/)

Comment: This is a link-only answer and could become invalid if the link becomes broken. Please include/quote any information which you deem useful from that link. :)

Comment: I am saying that you should include relevant information for that link. For detailed explanation, [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/261883)

Answer (score 5):

Push notifications will work no matter what IDE you're using, but I have two pieces of advice for you:

1. You need to migrate your project to Android Studio for better support.
2. Your GCM registration library GCMRegistrar is too old. You need to get the latest version, checkout [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start).

Hope this helped :)